# How to run a phalcon project in localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, phalcon

I am using xampp and windows machine.

I am trying to run a existing phalcon project in my pc .

If i try **"localhost/odc/public"** , it runs the project but could not load any styling.

So i think if i can project with url localhost ,  it will solve the problem.
After going through online, i found that i need to edit **apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**.

So I tried the following , but didn't work.

```
<VirtualHost localhost>
    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/odc/public"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/xampp/htdocs/odc/public">
        Require all granted    
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: if its phalcon v4 you probably have the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62711091/2640796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one things to know

when you talk about phalcon 
you talk about the extension php

so if you have this extension installed in your server

you dont need to  touche any virtual configs

so the problem is coming from the website configurations
so maybe the are a link from your database that not the same at the url that you use 
to access to that project

maybe the website used  for example (style.css)
http://localhost/abc/public/style.css

and the script by default use the racine path (../style.css)
http://localhost/style.css

so here the problem comes from :)

try to check the **project configs** 
or maybe 
you have a **file .htaccess missed** 
or maybe 
you need to **put files directly in htdocs/  not in htdocs/odc/**

(sorry if my english is not good enough ;) )
greetings .